# How to prevent click event and bypass scroll events on a view?

Tags: android

I have a RelativeLayout above a NestedScrollView. I would like to prevent the propagation of any clicks on the RelativeLayout but allow all the scroll events.
It should be applied to the RelativeLayout with the "controllers_container" id

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        ... content ...

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/scrollView"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|end">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/controllers_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_bar">

            ... content ...

        </RelativeLayout>

        ... content ...

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Adding `android:clickable="true"` prevents any touch events, including scroll. I tried setting a touch listener to the scrollView, but couldn't manage it as desired. Any ideas?

Comment: try byepassing touch events to parent layout and handle it there using onTouchIntercept

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way of doing it.
Basically, I had a view inside the NestedScrollView handling touch events (call it **targetView**). I created a public method that handles the touch event, like that:

```
public boolean handleTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            ... Handle the action up event ...

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Then, I set the on touch listener of that view on the parent (in that case, the fragment that contains all these elements). If the action up happened outside the **controllersContainer**, I call the **handleTouch** method.

```
targetView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    int scrollY = nestedScrollView.getScrollY();
                    int top = controllersContainer.getTop();
                    float y = event.getY() + targetView.getTop();
                    if (y - scrollY > top) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return targetView.handleTouch(v, event);
            }
        });
```